# Angular 2.0.0 final - Custom Pipe Filter Returns [object Object]

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I'm trying to create a filter using a custom pipe.
Can anyone help to see why the filter isn't filtering the mock data?
It does not throw an error, it returns [object Object]

You can find the full code here:
http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/qwsk86hHLbI26w3HVMdV/

Comment: `{{listFilter.name}}` simple ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing "Filtered by: [Object object]" because the value of `listFilter` is really an object, not a string.

You bind `listFilter` here:

```
<select type="string" [(ngModel)]="listFilter" (ngModelChange)="showSelected()">
    <option *ngFor="let foodType of foodTypes" [ngValue]="foodType">{{foodType.name}}</option>
</select>
```

When an item is selected, `listFilter` will be set to the appropriate value of the `foodTypes` array, which is defined in `app.ts`:

```
foodTypes = [
  { id: 1, name: "Fruits" },
  { id: 2, name: "Spices" },
  { id: 3, name: "Vegetables" }
];
```

So `listFilter` will be an object with the keys `id` and `name`. Use the `name` property in your template to show the filter name, e.g:

```
<div *ngIf='listFilter'>
  <h5>Filtered by: {{listFilter.name}} </h5>
</div>
```

As for why the list itself isn't being filtered, you're not yet doing anything to filter the products list. You'll want to do something like:

```
<tr *ngFor='let _product of (_products|productFilter:listFilter)'>
  <td>{{ _product.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ _product.prodName }}</td>
</tr>
```

and then implement the filter itself appropriately:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: IProduct[], filterObject: any): IProduct[] {
        // your code here -- return the filtered list
    }
}
```

(If you defined an interface for the filter object, you could use it here instead of the `any` type.)

Check out the angular guide on pipes for more info:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: Thanks, that was really easy! :) That prints out the selected option to the view as expected, however the filtering doesn't seems to work and there is no error either... Can anyone let me know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you read the second half of my answer? You need to apply your pipe to your elements using the `|` operator and them come up with some appropriate implementation for your pipe to actually filter the elements.